# Python JSON loads/dumps breaks Unicode?

Tags: python, json, unicode

Dumping a string that contains unicode characters as json produces weird unicode escape sequences:

```
text = "⌂⚘いの法嫁"
print(text) # output: ⌂⚘いの法嫁

import json
json_text = json.dumps(text)
print(json_text) # output: "\u2302\u2698\u3044\u306e\u6cd5\u5ac1"
```

I'd like to get this output instead:

```
"⌂⚘いの法嫁"
```

How can I dump unicode characters as characters instead of escape sequences?

Comment: how about: json_string = unicode( r.text )

Comment: It is not broken; `\u` _four-hex-digits_ is an allowed representation of a Unicode character in JSON.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Call [`json.dumps`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps) with `ensure_ascii=False`:

```
json_string = json.dumps(json_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
```

On Python 2, the return value will be `unicode` instead of `str`, so you might want to `encode` it before doing anything else with it.